# Why does weight Bevel deform my mesh?

Tags: modifiers, edges, topology, bevel

I am currently applying a Bevel modifier with weights on my gun to smooth out all the edges and essentially finish the design, however it some edges get deformed, even if the topology seems fine. Why does this happen? [image]

[image]

Comment: Looks as if you may have inverted normals on some of the faces. Enable Face Orientation in the viewport overlay dropdown and see if any faces are shown in red. If they are, go into Edit mode, select All with 'A' and press SHFT-N.

Comment: Thank you so much! Cant believe all I had to do was recalculate outside :D

Comment: No problem. It's not really worth posting a full answer to that one as it's been asked and answered here so frequently.

Comment: Ah well as it would turn out, I spoke too soon xD. While the majority of the edges resolved one specific edge still seems to become distorted.